# Application silently terminates at launch Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sdf

I created simple WP8 application with database and I am having problems trying to submit it to store. Application is quite simple it allows to search through database that I attach to application. Everything works fine using all emulators and Lumia 620, but I am unable to successfully submit it to store. When I set my `Database.sdf` `Build action` to `Embedded Resource` I get following certification error:

> The application cannot be tested for compliance for Windows Phone Application Certification Requirements because it fails
>   to launch on all Windows Phone devices. The application silently terminates at launch.

But when I changed `Build action` to `Content` application passed certification and was published to store. To make sure that everything works fine I downloaded it and was unable to run it, it closed immediately...

I managed to reproduce this error by opening `MyApplication.xap` and renaming `Database.sdf` to something else. So I think problem is with encryption and I should reference database in code differently, but not sure how. Any ideas ?

`DbDataContext context = new DbDataContext(@"Data Source = 'appdata:/Database.sdf';");`